# Where on the website is it appropriate to ask for advice?

Tags: support

I am young, and have a few questions about the profession for older mathematicians.  On what part of the website is it appropriate to ask them?  Thanks,

Comment: There is an "advice" tag on the main site. If you look at the questions with that tag, about half of them get closed as being off-topic, especially the ones that aren't about any specific mathematical topic. So you can post your question to math.stackexchange, but there's a fair chance it will get a negative reception.

Comment: Try Academia.se.

Comment: There is also chat. If you have [sufficient reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat) you can ask, for example, in [the main chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/36). And if you expect a longer discussion, it sometimes  makes sense even to [create a separate room](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms).

Comment: I see.  Thanks for the options.